# Example of a linear operator whose graph is not closed

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, unbounded-operators

I want an example of a linear operator $T:X\to Y$ such that graph of $T$ is not closed.

My thoughts: $T$ must be unbounded. Again by closed graph theorem any unbounded linear map from a Banach space $X$ to another Banach space $Y$ should have non-closed graph. But it is not possible to define any unbounded linear map from  a Banach space $X$ to another Banach space $Y$ explicitly without axiom of choice. Thus to get such an example at least one of $X$ and $Y$ must be incomplete. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: So: you ask the question only for Banach spaces?  (Examples are easy for normed spaces that are not complete.)  It is consistent with ZF that every linear map from one Banach space to another is continuous [Solovay?].  Thus (without AC) we cannot explicitly write down an operator with graph not closed.

Answer (score 2):

If $T$ is everywhere defined and closed, then it is continuous. [See this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem_(functional_analysis))

If you mean densely-defined $T$, then it's not so hard. The (strong) derivative operator $d/dx$ defined on (a dense subset of) $L^2(-1,1)$ is closable (its closure is the weak derivative), but not closed. To see that it is not closed, Let $u_n(x)$ be a sequence of functions converging to $|x|$ suitably strongly, with $v_n(x) = u_n'(x)$ converging to the weak derivative of $|x|$, which is $x/|x| = sign(x)$. Then because $|x|$ is not in the domain of $T$, this thing is not closed.

The formula $u_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + n^{-1}}$ fits the bill.

Comment: Can't we get an incomplete space X and a linear operator $T:X\to Y$ whose graph is not closed?

Answer (score 2):

On $L^2(R)$, consider the densely defined operator $u\mapsto \int u\,dx$, defined on $L^2\cap L^1$. This operator is neither closed nor closable. If you want the operator defined on all of X, with X incomplete, just take X to be $L^2\cap L^1$ with the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little?